# Make Dictionary from 2D Array Python?

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have a 2D array as follows.

```
[['FE0456143', '218.04'], ['FB1357448', '217.52'], ['FB1482960', '222.70'], ['FB1483107', '223.32'], ['FE0456556', '12429.67'], ['FE0456594', '213.71'], ['FB1483056', '218.86'], ['FE0456061', '12392.33'], ['FB1482479', '223.35']]
```

The first element is the key while the second is the value. I have tried:

```
keys = zip(*data)[0]
vals = zip(*data)[1]
dic(zip(keys,vals))
```

However some elements of the array may have duplicate keys, and the elements are not corresponding to them?  I want all of the keys to have 3 values associated with it?

Comment: FYI, ,you can create your dictionary using `dict(data)`

Comment: @MartinKonecny for some reason that cuts off a few values associated with similar keys??

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a `1 to many` mapping. You can have this if you make your value a `list`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in data:
    d[k].append(v)
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the deafultdict use! Exactly what i was looking for!